# Extending OSGi's HttpService

Tags: java, osgi

In the OSGi world, you can register a `Servlet` using

```
HttpService.registerServlet(String alias, Servlet servlet, Dictionary initParams, HttpContext context);
```

So, for a bundle with a `SymbolicName` `foo.bar`, I could do

```
HttpService.registerServlet("/foo", new FooServlet(), null, null);
```

I want to extend this registerServlet method to ensure that the `alias` starts with the bundle's `SymbolicName`, i.e. "/foo.bar". I need to do this to provide URL namespace isolation between bundles based on their `SymbolicName`, so they don't accidentally register servlets at the same alias.

What is the best way to achieve this, other than modifying the implementation of `HttpService`? Are there any service extension hooks where I could add my validation logic? Could I somehow extend `HttpService` and override `registerServlet` method and hide the existing one?

I am using Apache Felix in the bridged mode.

Answer (score 0):

When you register a servlet, the `Servlet.init` is called. Maybe you can do some check in there?